# Simple Game Server using Post commands

Tags: php, android

I am attempting to write a simple game server for an Android game using php with a mysql database.

My idea is to simply have the 'droid application simulate a simple http post request
e.g http://www.mysite.com/missile/new.php?lat=58123456,long=-2123456,state=1

My web server is intended to then store a new missile as being launched in an mysql database from those E6 co-ords and then I intend to write another php file to allow all clients to peridoically check for missiles in flight.

I've tried out various bits of code I've found but with no 100% success.

If I type http://www.mysite.com/missile/new.php?lat=58123456,long=-2123456,state=1 into a browser bar - I get back
Array ( [launchlat] => 56123456,launchlong=2700123,state=0 ) because I'm just doing a simple

```
print_r($_GET);
echo '<br />';
```

in my php file.

However with my current code

```
           try {
                    String reply;
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            String postURL = "http://www.mysite.com/missile/new.php";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL); 
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("launchlat", "56123456"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("launchlong", "2700123"));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", "0"));
                UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
                post.setEntity(ent);
                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);  
                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity();  
                if (resEntity != null) {    
                    reply = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                    Log.i("RESPONSE",reply);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm getting an empty array in reply.

Can anyone suggest a tweak (or completely new code to do the post and receive the reply please?

regards

Simon

Comment: Your PHP responds to the browser method and not the Android program. My tool in debugging something like this is Wireshark. Capture the post-response from the browser, then capture the post (no respose) from Android. The comparison of the packets should yeild a good clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know anything about android dev, but it seems like you are using `HttpPost` but your php is expecting a `GET`.

Change your php to look in `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.
If you need both GET and POST use `$_REQUEST`

Comment: What a fool :)  Thanks for pointing out my faulty thinking :) Changing to echo print_r($_GET); gives the expected reply from my code :)